# Twitter API update in Flash Action Script V2.0

Tags: api, twitter, actionscript

I need to update Twitter API v1.1 from Flash Action Script 2.0 version that currently I'm using in a flash file. Any solution available without upgrading the action script to v3.0?

Answer (score 1):

- Open the fla file using flash.
- Press CTRL+SHIFT+F12 (this will bring up the publishing settings of your fla.)
- Go to the Flash tab
- Change Player: to Flash Player 9 (or higher)
- Change Script: to Actionscript 3.0 (if you didn't change Player: first then you won't see the option for Actionscript 3.0)